# Line connecting the half of a triangle height with its side.

Tags: geometry, triangles, median

The isosceles triangle ABC (AC=BC) has a height CC1. Point E is part of BC where EB = 2CE. 
If AE crosses CC1 in point D, prove that CD=DC1.

[image: Graphical explaination]

Answer (score 1):

I will use Mass Point Geometry.

C has mass 2 and B has mass 1 using the given ration.

AC1=BC1 as C1 is the foot of the altitude in an isosceles triangle where AC=BC, so CC1 is also a median.

Then, the mass of B is equal to the mass of A which must now be 1.

The mass of C1=massA+massB=2.

C has mass 2 and Cq has mass 2, equal masses mean CD=DC1.

You could also show the result using coordinate geometry,  perhaps with origin at C1.

Answer (score 1):

Let [.] denote triangle areas.

$$\frac{CD}{C_1D} = \frac{[ACE]}{[AC_1E]} = \frac{\frac13[ABC]}{\frac12[ABE]}
=\frac{\frac13[ABC]}{\frac12\cdot\frac23[ABC]}=1$$

where we used the facts that triangles $ACE$ and $AC_1E$ share their base side $AE$.

Comment: How can I prove that CD/C1D = [ACE]/[AC1E]?

Comment: @RadiCho - since they share the base AE, the area ratio is equal to their height ratio, which is equal to $CD/C_1D$ from similar triangles.